# 'The model backing the '' context has changed since the database was created' - in different project

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using EF with Code First Approach and I have a static method that is used for authentication. If I call it inside the project, it works fine, if I however call it from a different project I get the following error:

The model backing the '' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database...

Any ideas why that might be happening?

Comment: What version of EF are you using? Have you tried scaffolding a new migration to see what the difference is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is:

1. Add Entity Framework to each project
2. Inside the project where you raise the database add Global.asax
3. Inside the Application_Start add the following line:

   Database.SetInitializer< Namespace.Entities>(null);

where `Namespace.Entities` is the address to your `DbContext`.